# How to get a value for an asp.net session parameter from property of session object

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net parameter

```html
<asp:SessionParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" SessionField="MySessionObject" DefaultValue="0"/>
```

I also have a session object `Session["MySessionObject]`

Session object is of type `Widget` which has *ID* and *Name* properties.

Is there a way to assign the *ID* value from *MySessionOjbect* to the asp.net SessionParameter or do I have to create a separate session variable for the ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asp:SessionParameter` is meant to be bound to a session variable and is typically used to include the value of an HttpSessionState variable in a sql data source query. Please check out this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and the example they use.

In your example, you are binding the `asp:SessionParameter` (which you state holds `Type="Int32"`) to your session state variable `Session["MySessionObject]`, which you say hold type `Widget` object. To bind it to the *ID* of your session state Widget object, you will need to create another session variable for the ID.

aspx:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="widgetID" Type="Int32" SessionField="widgetID" DefaultValue="0"/>
```

code-behind(c#):

```
Widget myWidget = (Widget) Session["MySessionObject"];
Session["widgetID"] = myWidget.ID;
```

---

**Update:**
You can try using a `asp:Parameter` instead to avoid creating another session object:

aspx:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0"/>
```

code-behind (c#):

```
Widget myWidget = (Widget) Session["MySessionObject"];
sqlDataSrc.SelectParameters["id"].DefaultValue = myWidget.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I knew that much ;) I was wondering if there was a way to do that in the asp:SessionParameter. I'm trying to avoid having to create another session variable.

Comment: @Rich Yeah, I was basically answering your question in that yes, you would need to create another session variable ;) See my edit for a different suggestion tho